# React Native app can't be started after upgrading to nodejs 12.13 from 10.13

Tags: node.js, react-native

My React Native used to run fine with 0.61.2 with Nodej 10.13. There is an error after upgrading to nodejs 12.13.0 when `react-native run-android`. Here is the error:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1461 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\D\code\js\emps_fe6\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 182

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Text must not be null or empty

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\D\code\js\emps_fe6\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 182

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Text must not be null or empty

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\d\code\js\emps_fe6\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\d\code\js\emps_fe6\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
    at C:\d\code\js\emps_fe6\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\d\code\js\emps_fe6\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:9)
```

`./gradlew clean` failed as well. What is wrong with the upgrade? Shall I roll back to nodejs 10.13?

Comment: `Text must not be null or empty`, try looking for this